# How do you find possible values for freq_list and/or scan_freq in wpa_supplicant.conf?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wpa-supplicant

The wpa_supplicant.conf file can have parameters freq_list and scan_freq. How do I find what are the possible values for either or both of these parameters?

```
freq_list=5500 5520 ... 

scan_freq=5500 5520 ...
```

I found a tool that can scan surrounding access points and return their frequencies: sudo iwlist scanning | grep -A 3 Address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments in the example `wpa_supplicant.conf` say, where you probably found it, the frequency is in MHz.

Allowed frequencies depend on your country. Wikipedia has a [list of channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels) with frequencies by country.

The command

```
iw reg get
```

prints out what the kernel thinks are the current admissible regulatory ranges for your WLAN devices.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a tool that can scan surrounding access points and return their frequencies?

Comment: I found a tool that can scan surrounding access points and return their frequencies: sudo iwlist scanning

Comment: `iwlist` is the old tool, try `iw wlan0 scan` (does new scan) and `iw wlan0 scan dump` (uses known values). While you are at it, also try `iw wlan0 station dump`.